# Looking for 80's movie with android and space mission

Tags: story-identification

I have been looking for ages for a movie I saw as a kid. Here's what I remember:

- must have been in the 80's (seen it somewhere around 1978-1985)
- there were human-like androids (>=1) involved, undistinguishable from humans
- even the androids didn't know they were artificial
- sometimes/at least once you see the first-person-view through the eyes of an android
- one android is put on a space travel mission with other humans
- the last hint is actually a spoiler:

> during this mission, they experience heavy g-forces. The android grabs some kind of guardrail, but his hands rip off, only then does he realize he is not a human.

Thanks for any pointers! :o)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this is [*Test pilota Prixa*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_pilota_Pirxa), after a short story by Stanisław Lem. German title "Testflug zum Saturn".

Comment: I'm pretty sure you are right! The description sounds familiar, the release date matches, and the fact that it's non-English explains why it's difficult to find anything about it on the internet :o) (in Germany, all movies and TV series are dubbed, so it's not obvious what the original language is)

Thanks a lot! ...just ordered the DVD... :-D